# Python buggy histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have a strange behavior with this very simple code

```
import numpy as np
[y, binEdges] = np.histogram(x, xout)
```

where x and xout are numpy arrays (xout describes the edges of the bins that are equally spaced).

If I do

```
np.sum(y)
```

the value is not equal to the number of elements in x (x.shape), this value is a lot lesser then x.shape and I cannot figure out why. Is it a bug of np.histogram? If you need I can upload the x and xout numpy arrays but they are very long (x.shape is 19133 float64 and xout.shape is 1360 float64). Let me know if I did something wrong in the above code.

Comment: maybe the actual range of values in x exceeds that of xout, can you try to do `np.histogram(x, bins-100)` to see whether the sum of y comes out right?

Comment: Hi, you are right xD np.max(xout) < np.max(x) xD sorry for the dummy question xD I did not check the maximum value of xout

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
y.sum() + (x < xout[0]).sum() + (x > xout[-1]).sum()
```

Comment: Thx, the problem now it is fixed xD read the above comments :) I initialized in wrong way the xout variable

Answer (score 1):

Use this to compute the `xout` correctly, **n** is the number of bins.

```
xout = np.linspace(floor(x.min()), ceil(x.max(), n)
```

and then call the histogram function:

```
[y, binEdges] = histogram(x, xout)
```

Comment: Thx, I fixed the problem xD read above comments xD the problem was xout